# Google maps ios when calling app via url scheme. bug with directions

Tags: ios, google-maps, url, swift

Im calling google maps directions from my app and im leaving the saddr as directed by google so it will locate the user's location asthe starting point and give directions to the daddr specified.

The problem is....

The first time u use it and some other times.. Google maps doesnt locate well and give wrong directions asif you where located someplacr else. How can i keep this from happening ?????????

What i have tried is leaving the saddr and guide by google url scheme so google maps will autolocate the user starting point and give the directions to the destination point. Its got it completly wrong

Comment: let me summarise it to see if I got it: you don't saddr parameter but the geocoded position found by google maps is not exact enough

Comment: Can you post your code related to this issue?

Comment: It appears to be the same bug as this one: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7197&q=apitype%3AIosSDK%20type%3ADefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars
You may mark it with a star, which will rise its priority.